# How to handle event invocation between injected classes in .NET Core Console App

Tags: c#, events, .net-core, dependency-injection, event-handling

I've a .Net Core(3.1) Console App, that has 2 service classes, one has an event and other listens to it with a handler to that event. I've setup getting the DI containers but the event field is always null, so not able to call its Invoke(). Any pointers on what am I missing in setting up the services in ConfigureServices() that involves event handling. Below is the complete test code:

```
public class RefreshEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string RefreshEventData { get; set; }
}
public interface INotifierService
{
    event EventHandler<RefreshEventArgs> RefreshEventHandler;
}

public class NotifierService : INotifierService
{
    public event EventHandler<RefreshEventArgs> RefreshEventHandler;
    public RefreshEventArgs RefreshEventData { get; set; }

    // GeneralAppSettings is a POCO class to read all appsettings.json key values.
    private readonly IOptions<GeneralAppSettings> myAppSettings;
    public NotifierService(IOptions<GeneralAppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        myAppSettings = appSettings;
    }
    
    public void RunInvokingRefreshEvent()
    {
        RefreshEventData = new RefreshEventArgs();
        RefreshEventData.RefreshEventData = "somedata";
        
        // Main problem! In the below line, RefreshEventHandler is null all the time           
        RefreshEventHandler?.Invoke(this, RefreshEventData);            
    }
    
    public void SomeBackgroundThreadMonitorsExternalEvents()
    {
        // Some external events triggers below method
        RunInvokingRefreshEvent();
    }       
}
```

Refresh Service

```
public interface IRefreshService
{
    void Refresh(RefreshEventArgs eventData = null);
}
public class RefresherService : IRefreshService
{
    private readonly IOptions<GeneralAppSettings> myAppSettings;
    private readonly INotifierService notify;

    public RefresherService(IOptions<GeneralAppSettings> _appSettings, INotifierService _notifyService)
    {
        myAppSettings = _appSettings;
        notify = _notifyService;
        notify.RefreshEventHandler += _notify_RefreshEventHandler;
    }

    private void _notify_RefreshEventHandler(object sender, RefreshEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call Refresh() based say based on a config value from myAppSettings
        Refresh(e);
    }
    public void Refresh(RefreshEventArgs eventData = null)
    {
        // final business logic processing based on eventData
    }
}
public class GeneralAppSettings // POCO
{
    public string SomeConfigKeyInAppSettingsJson { get; set; }      
}
```

Program

```
class Program
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // read appsettings
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        // Host builder, setting up container 
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<GeneralAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GeneralAppSettings"));
                services.AddSingleton<INotifierService, NotifierService>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRefreshService, RefresherService>();
            })
            .Build();
        
        // Need to get NotifierService instance to run some initial logic, so using ActivatorUtilities
        var svc = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<NotifierService>(host.Services);
        svc.SomeBackgroundThreadMonitorsExternalEvents();      

        // Need to get RefresherService instance to have initial Refresh logic so using ActivatorUtilities
        var refresh = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<RefresherService>(host.Services);
        refresh.Refresh(null);
        
        // need to keep this main thread alive 
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you want to use `INotifierService` instead of `NotifierService` for the type in the ActivatorUtilities call?  Same with `IRefreshService`.  OR directly get both instances from the ServiceProvider you just created w/o using `ActivatorUtilities`?

Comment: @jimnkey, As the NotifierService has dependencies in its constructor(IOptions<GeneralAppSettings>), we need to use 
ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance with concrete type to resolve that otherwise you would get INotifier type could not be located error. Yes, normally we use interface to get instance but here its a special case with console app where we start off the app with actual concrete type but it will still use the services to populate the constructor.

Comment: I believe your `NotifierService` instance from `ActivatorUtilities` is NOT the instance that your SP has registered.  You have registered `INotifierService` as your singleton and your SP only knows how to create that interface -- even though `NotifierService` is your implementation.  I suspect that `ActivatorUtilities` gives you back a new/different instance of `NotifierService` than what  `RefresherService` gets -- because `RefresherService` will get the `INotifierService` that your SP knows how to create.

Comment: If you're gojng to request it with the concrete type, you need to register it with the concrete type. Ie `AddSingleton<RefresherService>()` that said your explanation for why you need to A. Use `ActivatorUtilities` directly and B. use the concrete type instead of the interface make absolutely zero sense. Just `GetService<IRefresherService>()` and be done with it. Console apps work exactly the same as a web app... After all a web app *is* a console app. And if this is all your code then you should have zero issue requesting the interface.

Comment: Oh I see now. The method you are calling on NotifierService doesn't exist on the interface. That's why you can't request the interface. In that case you need to register and request it as the concrete type as per my comment above. That said, NotifierService should absolutely be an IHostedService (or BackgroundService) instead. Then all these issues go away magically solved by proper use of the framework. The problem then is that your refresher service takes an instance of INotifierService. Which obviously isn't going to work since you'd need to register it as the concrete type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request something from the DI container, you **must** request the "Service" type (the interface or first/only generic argument). If you request a type that's not been registered and you use `ActivatorUtilities`, it will create an instance if and only if all the types required to construct it are available. What's happening to you is you are getting two distinct objects (one registered as the interface and one pseudo-registered as the concrete type)! It doesn't matter that your class implements the interface and you've used it as the "Implementation" type in the registration. DI is **always** based on the service type and you've not registered any services of type `NotifierService` *directly*.

Your problem is that you have a weird coupling between your classes and the method you want to call on `NotifierService` isn't actually part of the interface. The usual trick would be to just register and request the concrete type as the service type:

```
services.AddSingleton<NotiferService>();
//...
var notifier = services.GetService<NotifierService>();
```

That would work, except now you haven't registered `INotifierService` for injection into the `RefresherService`.

Never fear, we have a work around. Register the concrete type as a singleton and then use a factory to register the interface:

```
// register the concrete type directly 
services.AddSingleton<NotifierService>();
// use a factory to register the interface 
services.AddSingleton<INotifierService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<NotifierService>());
```

Now, the same instance will be returned whether you are requesting the interface or the concrete type. You no longer need to use `ActivatorUtilities` either (in fact you **shouldn't**)--you can now use the host's services directly:

```
var notifier = host.Services.GetRequiredService<NotifierService>();
notifier.SomeBackgroundThreadMonitorsExternalEvents();
```

All that said, you're project is a perfect candidate for an `IHostedService`/`BackgroundService`. You can restructure it a bit (splitting `NotifierService` into two classes: one with just the event and the other for the background service) such that you'll then only be dealing with interfaces *and* you'd be able to actually call `Host.Run()` which will in turn wait for shutdown. This is the standard pattern for things like this, rather than abusing the Host simply for the DI container and including the weird `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explanation. Will consider your suggestions.